# Recursive Hierarchical Join in Python DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am used to using SQL to solve hierarchical joins but I'm wondering if it can be done in Python, maybe using Pandas. And which one is more efficient to go for?

CSV Data:
`emp_id,fn,ln,mgr_id
1,Matthew,Reichek,NULL
2,John,Cottone,3
3,Chris,Winter,1
4,Sergey,Bobkov,2
5,Andrey,Botelli,2
6,Karen,Goetz,7
7,Tri,Pham,3
8,Drew,Thompson,7
9,BD,Alabi,7
10,Sreedhar,Kavali,7`

I want to find the Level of each employee (Boss is Level 1 and so on):

[image]

My Recursive Code in SQL would be:

```
with recursive cte as
    (
    select employee_id, first_name, last_name, manager_id, 1 as level
    from icqa.employee
    where manager_id is null
    union 
    select e.employee_id, e.first_name, e.last_name, e.manager_id, cte.level + 1
    from icqa.employee e
    inner join cte
        on e.manager_id = cte.employee_id
    where e.manager_id is not null
    ) 

select * from cte
```

Comment: can you briefly explain the logic of finding level?

Comment: We find the level by identifying who is the manager of each employee. BOSS has no manager so Level 1. then those reporting to Boss would be Level 2, then the next level will be 3 and so on.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could make a dict mapping `emp_id` to `mgr_id` and then make a recursive function like

```
idmap = dict(zip(df['emp_id'], df['mgr_id']))
def depth(id_):
    if np.isnan(id_):
        return 1
    return depth(idmap[id_]) + 1
```

to compute the depth given an `id`. 
To make it more efficient (by not repeating calculations for the same `id`),
you could use memoization (handled by the [`@functools.lru_cache` decorator](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.lru_cache) below):

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import functools
nan = np.nan
df = pd.DataFrame({'emp_id': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10], 'fn': ['Matthew', 'John', 'Chris', 'Sergey', 'Andrey', 'Karen', 'Tri', 'Drew', 'BD', 'Sreedhar'], 'ln': ['Reichek', 'Cottone', 'Winter', 'Bobkov', 'Botelli', 'Goetz', 'Pham', 'Thompson', 'Alabi', 'Kavali'], 'mgr_id': [nan, 3.0, 1.0, 2.0, 2.0, 7.0, 3.0, 7.0, 7.0, 7.0]})

def make_depth(df):
    idmap = dict(zip(df['emp_id'], df['mgr_id']))
    @functools.lru_cache()
    def depth(id_):
        if np.isnan(id_):
            return 1
        return depth(idmap[id_]) + 1
    return depth

df['depth'] = df['mgr_id'].apply(make_depth(df))
print(df.sort_values(by='depth'))
```

yields

```
   emp_id        fn        ln  mgr_id  depth
0       1   Matthew   Reichek     NaN      1
2       3     Chris    Winter     1.0      2
1       2      John   Cottone     3.0      3
6       7       Tri      Pham     3.0      3
3       4    Sergey    Bobkov     2.0      4
4       5    Andrey   Botelli     2.0      4
5       6     Karen     Goetz     7.0      4
7       8      Drew  Thompson     7.0      4
8       9        BD     Alabi     7.0      4
9      10  Sreedhar    Kavali     7.0      4
```