# Pandas derive order by using "From" & "To" columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, sorting

I have the following df:

| Name | From | To | Final |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Tony | C | D | D |
| Tony | B | C | D |
| Tony |  | A | D |
| Tony | A | B | D |
| Mark |  | A | C |
| Mark | A | B | C |
| Mark | B | C | C |

I can tell that Tony's data isn't sorted correctly because, unlike Mark, his data doesnt start with a blank **From** column and doesn't end with the **To** column matching with the final column. Most importantly, I can tell Tony's data isn't sorted because the value of the **To** column doesn't match up with the previous value in the **From** column.

I would like to find a way to sort this df based on the above (and per name) where all the data looks like Marks.

Comment: Is it always 1:1, or can one parent row relate to multiple child rows? (If it's the simple case then it's just a depth calculation ; https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54962616/recursive-hierarchical-join-in-python-dataframe )

Comment: Yup, always 1:1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems like a Graph problem :

```
#pip install networkx
import networkx as nx
    
def sort_from_to(g):
    G = nx.from_pandas_edgelist(g, source="From", target="To")
    eul_paths = nx.eulerian_path(G, source="NONE")
    
    return (pd.DataFrame(eul_paths, index=g.index, columns=["From", "To"])
                 .replace({"NONE": float("nan")})).join(g["Final"])

out = (df.fillna({"From": "NONE"}).groupby("Name", sort=False)
           .apply(sort_from_to).reset_index(level=0))
```

Output :

```
print(out)

   Name From To Final
0  Tony  NaN  A     D
1  Tony    A  B     D
2  Tony    B  C     D
3  Tony    C  D     D
4  Mark  NaN  A     C
5  Mark    A  B     C
6  Mark    B  C     C

[7 rows x 4 columns]
```

Comment: Thanks this worked really well. While I have you, I noticed that I had some examples where the from and to were the same and it throws an error. Would you know how to get around that error?